# What is the best RDP/VNC client for the new iPad that makes use of the retina display?

Tags: remote-desktop, ipad, display

I am looking for a remote desktop client to connect to both my Mac and PC. I would prefer not to install any software on the remote computers and just take advantage of the built-in protocols. What are some of the best remote desktop apps that you have tried?

Comment: i'd hold up a bit on the demands for retina support… the iPad came out yesterday lol..

Comment: True but I'm sure developers plan for these things.  Waiting a bit would prob be best though when there is more competition.

Answer (score 6):

[Screens](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-client-for-ios/id400012962?mt=8) by [edovia](http://edovia.com/en/) supports retina resolution on the iPad from day one for the iPad and works well on iPod touch, iPad and iPhone for quite some time.

Here are pictures showing the same desktop in retina and then non-retina iPad screen captures.

Retina:

[image: full screen retina view - 24 inch cinema display to iPad 3rd generation]
[image: zoomed retina view - 24 inch cinema display to iPad 3rd generation]

Non-Retina:

[image: full screen retina view - 24 inch cinema display to iPad 1st generation]
[image: zoomed retina view - 24 inch cinema display to iPad 1st generation]

Oddly, when you zoom in to the maximum zoom level (and you will likely need to expand these pictures if you are not viewing them on a retina display or they get down sampled to render on this site), the non retina iPad anti-aliases text a bit better than the retina iPad where you can really see the anti aliasing. This is similar to scanning print magazines where a lower resolution is often better for digitizing the "human perception" and not the "reality" of [halftone screen details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone) in [process color printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model).

Comment: I need to upload a zoomed version of these - can hardly tell the difference on the main screen view.. The difference is very real in person, though

Answer (score 2):

I use an application called [iRemoteDesktop](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iremotedesktop/id343556263?mt=8). It's fairly inexpensive, uses native RDP and works perfectly for PC. I haven't used anything for Mac thought, since I have no need to remote to my Mac's.

As for supporting Retina displays, I am guessing most of these will be updated in the coming weeks, keep in mind, the new iPad was only released last week.